# SciFi book - designer virus taken as party drug

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for the name of a book, the remembered details are:

-I read this book some time between the years 2010 and 2015.
-The copy of the book was an A5 (?) paperback in poor condition, English language, found in a shared secondary-school/college library.

The designer "party drug" viruses could cause a group hallucination of almost any specific thing or character - at one point, the protagonist realises that he must have inhaled an infected sample because he could clearly see a "blue fairy" or pixie of some sort flitting around his apartment.

- Protagonist made designer virus samples for use as mind-altering drugs.

  - He lived in a cheap apartment.
  - His fridge was filled with bottles of a discontinued brand of a possibly cinnamon flavoured soda.
  - The Soda was named 'Faggio' or similar
- Blue-skinned genetically engineered humanoids were kept as pets and gladiators

  - IIRC, the festival time we see a Blue-skin is in a train station - it is the pet of a wealthy woman.
  - At one point wealthy humans with guns and armour fought unarmed Blue-skins for sport.
- One blue-skin is described as having a ridge on top of their skull in order to anchor the enlarged muscles needed to use their "prognathous jaw" in combat.
- There is a squad of genetically modified accelerated-growth clone soldiers

  - They are muscular and bloodthirsty but their voices sound like overgrown hormonal 14-year-olds.
- There is a little girl who displays disturbingly mature and manipulative behaviour

  - she initially controls the protagonist through threats of accusing him of sexually molesting her.
  - She is somehow involved with the MegaCorp
  - Later it is revealed that she was some sort of experimental prodigy.
- Victims of a virus have formed a massive swarm

  - They try to infect the uninfected by forcible fluid exchange
  - One news reporter was dragged down by a mob and forcibly kissed by a 'hag' or 'crone'.
- The Werewolf or 'Loup-Garou' is a soldier who has had artificial bloodlust implanted in him by some perhaps surgical means.

  - This is a problem because he is a deserter and the system is malfunctioning, causing him to commit violent acts uncontrollably.
- Later in the book, references to a sort of Fairyland begin.

  - This is where the weirdest of engineered life congregate and aggressively prevent themselves from being discovered by regular humans.

**Does anyone know this book?**

(P.S. bless the editor/s for making sense of my rambling. Thank you.)

Comment: Great details there, also check out [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/21267) to see if it helps jog your memory and add any more details, such as when you read it or when it might have been published.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Fairyland](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/654617.Fairyland) by Paul McAuley

> In the next century, an underground chemist meets and becomes obsessed
>   with Milena, a child genius who is the ultimate product of
>   gene-splicing technology. Milena is an advocate of the
>   dolls--artificial constructs that have replaced extinct companion
>   animals. Milena wishes to free the dolls from bondage--but in doing
>   so, she creates an autonomous race that may be a threat to mankind.

The soda is named Pisant:

> He gets a quick shot of reassurance from a couple of tabs of Cool-Z,
>   which he washes down with that day's carton of Pisant, this orange
>   cinnamon drink he discovered in a vending arcade on the Tot-tenham
>   Court Road. Pisant lasted about a week in the frenzied sharkpool of
>   niche marketing, probably because of the name, but Alex tracked down
>   the supplier before it disappeared, and the last of the world's supply
>   of Pisant is stacked in one of his three industrial fridges.

There's this description of blue-skinned doll:

> It is a blue-skinned doll, heavily modified by selective somatic
>   mutation or surgery. Probably both, Alex thinks. It's naked - and
>   female, although its dugs are little more than enlarged nipples. The
>   wide powerful jaws are like something found on an old tree bole
>   blasted by lightning and infected with fungus and rot, layers of
>   knotted cankerous growth. The doll has a crest of muscle on the top of
>   its skull to work these big jaws, a nose so flattened that the
>   nostrils are slits, little black eyes close set under a craggy brow.